# How to use Webmin - Cluster software package installer in CentOS

Tags: installation, package, cluster-computing, yum, webmin

I am using Webmin 1.590 on a cluster of machines running CentOS 6.2
I am particularly interested in the Cluster management part of Webmin.

I am trying to install packages using the **cluster software package installer**
There is an option called **Package from YUM** which always throws the following error:
**Failed to install on 192.168.12.34 : An error occurred installing the specified updates**

Any idea why this might be happening?

The following are two links that I found while searching for this error, both of them haven't been answered yet
[sourceforge -webmin error](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webadmin/forums/forum/600155/topic/4671253/index/page/1)
[another post regarding the same error](http://marc.info/?l=webmin-l&m=123793608124077)